# Why does adding time to a date in a loop not work in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to do the following:

```
startDate = Date
endDate = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, startDate)

currentDate = startDate
Do While DateDiff("d", endDate, currentDate) <> 0
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
        .Offset(i, 0).Value = currentDate
    End With
    currentDate = DateAdd("d", -1, currentDate)
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

to loop from startDate to endDate and output every date in between. After the first iteration currentDate equals the minimum date (1899).
I know there are other ways to do this and I have a way that works now, but why does this fail?

Comment: I put your code in a function and it ran fine. Have you stepped through it in debug to see where the problem is in your copy?

Comment: Yes, many times and it just wouldn't work. After the first iteration currentDate became 1899/01/01. Second iteration then failed. Which version of Excel did you test it in?

Comment: Turns out this is most likely a problem specific to my machine (or me going crazy...). Please consider this question closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code worked fine for me

Yoo could actually avoid the loop by either

- adding a worksheet function to the time span of interest
- dumping a function to a variant array direct to the sheet (as below)

**`code`**

```
Sub Test2()
Dim x
Dim dtStart As Date
Dim lngStart As Long
'test for leap year
lngStart = 365
If Year(Now()) Mod 4 = 0 Then
If Year(Now()) Mod 25 = 0 Then lngStart = lngStart + 1
End If

dtStart = Date
x = Application.Evaluate("NOW()-row(1:" & lngStart & ")+1")
With [a1].Resize(UBound(x, 1), 1)
.Value = x
.NumberFormat = "d/mm/yyyy;@"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could do that. I'm actually doing other stuff in the loop, but this might work for that as well. I still don't get why the code didn't work for me though...

Comment: +1 Nice one :) @user643192: A Dumb Question... When you type `=Now()` in a cell in Excel what date do you get? The Year `1899` is pretty suspicious... `1900 - 1 = 1899`

Comment: @user643192: Open Excel. In an Excel Cell Type this formula `=Now()` and press enter. What do you get?

Comment: I get the current date and time.

Comment: @user643192: Somehow it is taking 1900 as the current Year.

Comment: @user643192: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17050/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-user643192)